# Second order estimates of Monge-Ampere equations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, elliptic-pde

In order to prove existence of solutions of real and complex Monge-Ampere equations in various modifications (e.g. as in the Calabi problem) one often uses the method of a priori estimates. One of the steps includes the $C^0$-estimate of the Laplacian of the unknown function. The only known to me methods to get it are modifications of the Pogorelov's method introduced originally for the real MA-equation (its version was also used in the proof of the Calabi-Yau theorem, please correct me if I am wrong).

**My question is whether there are other methods to get the $C^0$-estimate of the Laplacian?**

Answer (score 3):

In the real case, one can also use a Harnack inequality for the linearized equation due to Caffarelli and Gutierrez ([here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/25098538)).

The idea goes as follows. If $\det D^2u = 1$, then by the concavity of the equation, $\varphi = \Delta u$ is a positive subsolution to the linearized equation:
$$u^{ij}\varphi_{ij} \geq 0.$$
A version of the mean value inequality holds for subsolutions to this equation, in an ellipsoidal geometry in which the balls are replaced by the level sets of $u$. If $u$ has zero boundary data on a domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ equivalent to $B_1$ up to dilations, then Caffarelli and Gutierrez show that these level sets have covering properties that are good enough to imitate the proof of the Krylov-Safonov Harnack inequality, giving
$$\varphi(0) \leq C(n) \int_{B_{1/2}} \varphi \,dx$$
(since $B_{1/2}$ contains some reasonably round level set of $u$), and since $\varphi = \Delta u$ and $u$ is locally Lipschitz, one sees that the right side is bounded by integrating by parts.

(Actually, The Harnack inequality for linearized Monge-Ampere only requires that $\det D^2u$ is bounded above and below by positive constants, but we need the right side to be nice to say that $\Delta u$ is a subsolution.)

Both this and the Pogorelov computation are based on on the observation that $\Delta u$ has no local maxima. While this method is more involved, advantages are that it doesn't require one to guess tricky cutoff quantities, and that it gives a helpful geometric understanding of the degeneracy/ affine invariance of the equation. A disadvantage is that it heavily relies on the convexity of $u$, which doesn't hold in e.g. the complex setting.

---

Also, in two dimensions (real case again) one has special techniques such as the partial Legendre transform (obtained by taking the Legendre transform along lines in some direction $e$). If $\det D^2u = 1$ then its transform $u^*$ is harmonic and $u^*_{ee} > 0$, and one can get an upper bound for $u_{ee}$ by using the Harnack inequality to get a positive lower bound for $u^*_{ee}$.